# How to split large qmainwindow code (if necessary)?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having a MainWindow with a lot of widgets, see the picture below (sorry for removing the names).

[image]

As you can see the window consists of a tabwidget and in every tab there is a toolbox widget. Every page in the toolbox widget consists of some buttons and a treewidget. The treewidgets in the different tabs and on the different pages can be influenced by each other. At this point I've written part of the ui signal handling code by basically just writing the actions in the mainwindow.cpp. However the code is already getting quite big (1445 lines) while I think I've only yet programmed 1/4.

I've read at multiple places that such big files generally mean that the code is not designed properly. So my question is:
**Is it a problem to write all ui signal handling within one file which might contain more than 6000 lines in the end?**

**If yes**, can you please give me tools on how to make it smaller. Currently I actually have one header with multiple source files to have a better overview. But according to some this still means your code is badly designed. I'm fine with making more classes but I just don't know how to (especially because my pages depend on each other). I though about making a class which has as member a Ui::MainWindowClass object, but the problem here is that I would lose the ability to use VS19 to the max as the ui widgets are not recognized anymore, i.e. VS will not list all the widget when typing `ui->` .

I'm aware of the following question: [With Qt, what are good ways to break up a large source file containing GUI logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34753435/10220019) but how I could modularize it (if necessary) is not clear enough for me.

**EDIT:** I like to keep using the Qt Designer. I'm not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: A 6000-line file is not a problem for the compiler (at least not on a modern machine); it might be a problem for a human reader/maintainer.  If you want to make it smaller, one thing to do is look through the code for sections of code that are identical (or nearly identical) to each other; when you find them, see if you can refactor so that the redundant code is removed (e.g. by moving the code into a separate function that can be called from multiple locations, possibly with different arguments, rather than keeping multiple copies of the code around)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I indeed did that at a certain point already. This saved me approximately 150 lines at that time. But indeed always a good idea to keep in mind!

Comment: ***I like to keep using the Qt Designer. I'm not sure if that makes any difference.*** It should not make a difference.

Comment: @drescherjm could you explain to me how I would make the custom widgets Fereanor is describing then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the couple *mainwindow.h* and *mainwindow.cpp* contains only the `MainWindow` implementation and nothing else that could be implemented elsewhere, I cannot see how it could be called bad design without seeing the code. The lines count cannot say if it was necessary/justified or not.
If the `MainWindow` implementation is heavy, splitting it through multiple files might make things even worse (or better, it depends).

A good practice is to define your custom sub-widgets separately and include them where they should be used. They don't need to be respectively declared and defined in *mainwindow.h* and *mainwindow.cpp*.
To be more clear, you can define `MyCustomTabWidget` in *mycustomtabwidget.h* and implement its behaviour in *mycustomtabwidget.cpp* then include the header in *mainwindow.h* (as the `MainWindow` is supposed to have a `MyCustomTabWidget` data member).

By the way, having a lot of lines is not a problem, it will just make the compilation last longer. I've already worked with softwares that contains a lot of long files counting all together a total around 1 million of lines (yes kind of hell).
It works fine, the compilation only takes more time than a 10 lines code obviously.
Another inconvenient is that the code becomes harder to read/maintain. But sometimes, we have no choice, some other times, we have. It depends.

Comment: Am I correct to say that one custom subwidget could for example be one page of the toolbox widget? Futhermore if I make subclasses, I can't use the Qt Designer anymore right?

Comment: An extra addition, I'm new to c++ or object oriented programming in general and my general opinion is that if you use to many classes that it more easily becomes more confusing instead of clearer. But I think that just arise from my habit of only coding with procedural languages

Comment: @C.Binair You are correct, each page is a widget. You can define it separately. However, it's up to you to define the limit when you have to split or not. But splitting for a widget that could be reused as is somewhere else (even if it is not but could be) is a good practice.

Comment: I never have used the Qt Designer so I can't tell if you'll be able to import your custom widget in the main ui file.

Answer (score 2):

You can break your tab widgets to individual widgets/class, you can even make the tab widget a separate class that handle initializing it's tabs, that depend on your code of course, but you can break your code to sub classes